# not all arguments converted during string formatting python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor

I am writing a script which prints the list items that are divisable by 3 XOR the last character ==4 but I get an error stating: `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` I am new to Python and may have missed something obvious. Code below:

```
lijst = ["124576", "795834", "890432", "907251"]    
for j in lijst:
if j[-1]==4 ^ j%3 > 0  :
    print(j)
```

Comment: Should be `int(j)%3`. You want to use `%` as an operator on a number, not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to change `4` to `'4'` because your items are string and convert the `j` to int in `j%3` also you need to parenthesis your comparison expression because the [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) of `^` is higher than `==` and it will raise a `TypeError` also if you want to preserve your result you can use a list comprehension :

```
>>> [j for j in lijst if (j[-1]=='4') ^ (int(j)%3 > 0)]
['124576', '795834', '890432']
```

If you just want to print the result you can use a usual loop with print function.